# Statement not supported: CreateIndexStatement

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

When creating an index in Google Cloud Spanner, I am getting a syntax error when I try to execute the most basic form of create index statement.
I am using the Cloud Console under the Query tab in Cloud Spanner.

The error I am getting is: `Statement not supported: CreateIndexStatement`
The query I am executing is: `CREATE INDEX SingersByFirstLastName ON Singers(FirstName, LastName)`

Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Query tab on the Cloud Console does not support executing DDL statements such as `CREATE INDEX`. The alternatives would be to:

- Click on the `Singers` table from the Overview page. You can then add an index through the user interface.
- Click on the link `Add Table` from the Overview page. That will open a page that allows you to enter DDL statements. Although the name kind of indicates that you can only add tables, it also allows you to enter a `CREATE INDEX` statement.
- Use a [tool like DBeaver to interact with Cloud Spanner](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-spanner-in-dbeaver-853998faa0ba), which will allow you to enter both queries, DML statements and DDL statements in the main SQL console.